# Fastest way to import from Excel to MVC3 Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm working on an import from a CSV file to my ASP.NET MVC3/C#/Entity Framework Application.

Currently this is my code, but I'm looking to optimise:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(file);
var data = from c in excel.Worksheet(0)
            select c;
var dataList = data.ToList();

List<FullImportExcel> importList = new List<FullImportExcel>();
foreach (var s in dataList.ToArray())
{
    if ((s[0].ToString().Trim().Length < 6) && (s[1].ToString().Trim().Length < 7))
    {
        FullImportExcel item = new FullImportExcel();
        item.Carrier = s[0].ToString().Trim();
        item.FlightNo = s[1].ToString().Trim();
        item.CodeFlag = s[2].ToString().Trim();

        //etc etc (50 more columns here)

        importList.Add(item);
    }
}

PlannerEntities context = null;
context = new PlannerEntities();
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
int count = 0;

foreach (var item in importList)
{
    ++count;
    context = AddToFullImportContext(context, item, count, 100, true);
}

private PlannerEntities AddToFullImportContext(PlannerEntities context, FullImportExcel entity, int count, int commitCount, bool recreateContext)
{
      context.Set<FullImportExcel>().Add(entity);

      if (count % commitCount == 0)
      {
          context.SaveChanges();
          if (recreateContext)
          {
              context.Dispose();
              context = new PlannerEntities();
              context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
          }
      }
      return context;
}
```

This works fine, but isn't as quick as it could be, and the import that I'm going to need to do will be a minimum of 2 million lines every month.  Are there any better methods out there for bulk imports?
Am I better avoiding EF altogether and using SQLConnection and inserting that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do like how you're only committing records every X number of records (100 in your case.)

I've recently written a system that once a month, needed to update the status of upwards of 50,000 records in one go - this is updating each record and inserting an audit record for each updated record.

Originally I wrote this with the entity framework, and it took 5-6 minutes to do this part of the task.  SQL Profiler showed me it was doing 100,000 SQL queries - one UPDATE and one INSERT per record (as expected I guess.)

I changed this to a stored procedure which takes a comma-separated list of record IDs, the status and user ID as parameters, which does a mass-update followed by a mass-insert.  This now takes 5 seconds.

In your case, for this number of records, I'd recommend creating a BULK IMPORT file and passing that over to SQL to import.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Cheers andy - it got my insert time right down.  Added full details in the answer below.  :)

Answer (score 2):

For large number of inserts in SQL Server Bulk Copy is the fastest way. You can use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class for accessing Bulk Copy from code. You have to create an IDataReader for your List or you can use [this](http://wimpool.nl/blog/DotNet/using-sqlbulkcopy-with-list-t) IDataReader for inserting generic Lists I have written.

Comment: This looks really good as well actually - would certainly be easier to do all this via the code.  I'll investigate this one too - thanks Wim

Comment: Did you succeed in implementing it in code? And how does the performance in code compare to sql Bulk Insert?

Comment: I did succeed actually, thanks.  I'm not sure the time taken to import was any quicker than Bulk Insert but the fact it allowed me to do it via the code was a big plus point.  Great bit of code...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andy for the heads up - this was the code used in SQL, with a little help from the ever helpful, Pinal Dave - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/ :)

```
DECLARE @bulkinsert NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @filepath NVARCHAR(100)
set @filepath = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\FullImport.csv'
SET @bulkinsert = 
    N'BULK INSERT FullImportExcel2s FROM ''' + 
    @filepath + 
    N''' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @bulkinsert
```

Still got a bit of work to do to work it into the code, but we're down to 25 seconds for 50000 rows instead of an hour, so a huge improvement!